# How Display a data on a page from database table in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some data in database table. I Don't know how display a data on page in wordpress

Comment: Have you already tried to do something? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ShortCode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) and [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) as for this senario eg:

```
function custom_table_data_callback( $atts ) {
   // Get Global WPDB Object
   global $wpdb;

   $data = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM your_table', output_type );

   //Then you can loop through the data variable

   foreach($data as $row){
          //Generate your table html here
   }     

}
add_shortcode( 'custom_table_data', 'custom_table_data_callback' );
```

After that use [custom_table_data] shortcode in you page.

Comment: Great solution, clean an simple.

Comment: glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to read the following Article:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb